# Наследование от абстрактного класса

Tags: c#, шаблоны-проектирования, абстрактная-фабрика

Есть следующий не большой проект:

**AbstractClass.cs**

```
public abstract class AbstractClass
{

}
```

**Gover.cs**

```
class Gover : AbstractClass
{

}
```

**Program.cs**

```
class Program
{
    public List<AbstractClass> list;
    void Main(string[] args)
    {
        list = new List<Gover>(); //Ошибка: Неявное преобразование типа "...List<abstrac.Gover>" в "...List<abstrac.AbstractClass>
    }
```

Но появляется (как показано выше) ошибка не понятная мне. Почему я не могу присвоит объекту AbstractClass объект Gover? Ведь Gover унаследован от AbstractClass?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как уже сказал @VladD, проблема в том, что `List<T>` не ковариантен по `T` (т.к. `List<T>` - класс, а классы в C# могут быть только инвариантны). Однако вместо него можно использовать реализуемый им ковариантный интерфейс `IEnumerable<T>`, чтобы сделать ваш код рабочим. Например:

```
public class Test
{
    public static IEnumerable<AbstractClass> list;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        list = new List<Gover>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Проблема вот в чём: `List<T>` не [ковариантен](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%B8_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C_%28%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%29) по `T`. Нормальными словами: Если `T1` — подкласс `T2`, то при этом `List<T1>` не подкласс `List<T2>`.

Почему это так? Смотрите. Допустим, что такое, как вы написали, было бы возможно:

```
public List<AbstractClass> list;

List<Gover> goverList = new List<Gover>();
list = goverList;
```

Тогда было бы возможно написать:

```
list.Add(new Gover2());
```

где `Gover2` — другой потомок `AbstractClass`. То есть в списке `goverList`, который вроде бы имеет тип `List<Gover>`, внезапно оказался бы элемент постороннего типа `Gover2`. Катастрофа!

---

Вывод: так, как вы написали, не получится. Пишите `list = new List<Gover>()`, например. Или сделайте тип списка шаблонным. Или ещё что-нибудь, в зависимости от того, что вам нужно.

Comment: Ох ты! Действительно. Спасибо @VladD.

Comment: @derkode: Пожалуйста!